# Doubts with command: pkill -INT -f '^php test_program.php$'

Tags: java, php, linux, terminal, kill-process

**QUESTION:** What does each element of the command:

```
pkill -INT -f '^php test_program.php$'
```

do when I run it in the linux terminal? I already know that the command kills the process called test_program.php, but I don't know what all the different elements of the command are doing. Please explain in as simple terminology as possible! I am new to linux commands and I prefer baby lingo to tech lingo at the moment :)

---

**MY RESEARCH:** By running `man pkill` in the linux terminal, a manual appears with the following `pkill` definition:

- signal processs based on their name or other attributes.

which leads me to believe that `pkill` doesn't only kill a process, but rather can send a lot of different signals, one of which might kill the process. The structure/synopsis of the `pkill` command was displayed as: `pkill [option] pattern`

From the list of options in the same manual, `-f, -full` had the following definition:

- The pattern is normally only matched against the process name. When -f is set, the full command line is used.

I didn't completely understand what that meant. Also, there is a `-INT` before the `-f` in the command, so that leads me to believe that more than one option can be joined together, however `-INT` was not displayed in the manual.

The other parts of the command seem to be identifying the program that is running: `'^php test_program.php$'`, but why isn't that part of the command just `'test_program.php'`? What does `^php` at the beginning and `$` and the end do?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a Regular Expression. This expression looks for the string `test_program.php` anywhere in the process name. So if the process name would be something like

```
/var/php -runcommand test_program.php
```

it would find the process and kill it.

This also explains the `-f, -full` option. Not using a Regular Expression, you would have to take the full process name (the preceeding line) to match the process.

Finally, the `-INT` is usually used to send a runlevel to the task.

**EDIT**

I was wrong, the `-INT` option is not used for runlevels (which are for the Linux kernel) but to send *signals* to a task. This could be something like `Term` (terminate), `Stop` (shut down) or `Cont` (continue process). `pkill` sends by default the terminate signal to the process.

The `/var/php -runcommand test_program.php` was an example for a process. If you use the command `ps ax`, you get a list of all processes and which programs execute them. So I just assumed that the php interpreter resides in `/var/php/` and the execution of the php file is a command.

Comment: I'm a bit new to the commands being used. I'm not quite sure what a runlevel is, also i'm not even sure what `/var/php -runcommand test_program.php` is doing, probably just running the program as I did with `php test_program.php`? And which part of the whole command is killing the process? because the definition of `pkill` was to signal commands, so if there are many commands, which one of the ones in the command line specified the "killing"?